# msbuild c++ : how do I supply desired version info as command line parameter?

Tags: c++, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, version

I'm building a C++ application on a CruiseControl.Net buildserver.

The build itself is done by msbuild and through cruisecontrol.net I have the desired version available - but I can't get it to be stamped into the c++ output.

Below is my msbuild project file.

Any comments are appreciated,

Anders, Denmark

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="FullBuild" ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
  <UsingTask TaskName="NCover.MSBuildTasks.NCover" AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files\NCover\Build Task Plugins\NCover.MSBuildTasks.dll"/>
  <UsingTask TaskName="NCover.MSBuildTasks.NCoverReporting" AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files\NCover\Build Task Plugins\NCover.MSBuildTasks.dll"/>

  <ItemGroup>
    <MyBinaries Include="Build\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CCNetLabel Condition="$(CCNetLabel)==''">2.0.0.0</CCNetLabel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Projects Include="$(vsproject)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Rebuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(Projects)" StopOnFirstFailure="true" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="version=$(CCNetLabel)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your buildscript, create a file (version.info) which will look like this:

```
#define BINVERSION 1,2,3,4
#define STRVERSION "1.2.3.4"
```

You might need to create a small utility to do that.

In your resourcefile, you will have a versioninfo rescource, the start will look like this:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,2,3,4
 PRODUCTVERSION 1,2,3,4
(...)
    VALUE "FileVersion", "1.2.3.4"
    VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.2.3.4"
```

Replace that with something like this:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION BINVERSION
 PRODUCTVERSION BINVERSION
(...)
    VALUE "FileVersion", STRVERSION
    VALUE "ProductVersion", STRVERSION
```

Don't forget to add `#include "version.info"` at the top of the resource file

When you now compile your application, it will have the correct versionnumber. (if you correctly created the version.info).

Also take a look at [Automatic Build Versioning in Visual Studio (codeproject)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/build_versioning.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just doing a search & replace on the .rc file.

Wimmels suggestion was good, but if I need to write a custom tool I might as well keep the rest simple. I tried out a single freeware search and replace tool, but it messes up the format of the rc file and it's really simple to do the replace yourself. For completeness, I include the code for search-replace below.

Thanks all!

Anders, Denmark

Target in msbuild project file:

```
<Target Name="UpdateVersion">
    <Exec Command="..\CCNetConfig\tools\SearchReplace\SearchReplace.exe project\project.rc $(CCNetLabel)"/>
  </Target>
```

Search & Replace:

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length!=2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Must call with two args:");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - File");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Version");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            var fileName = args[0];
            var version = args[1];
            var commaVersion = version.Replace(',', '.');

            var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Count(); i++)
            {

                allLines[i] = allLines[i].Replace("1.0.0.1", version);
                allLines[i] = allLines[i].Replace("1,0,0,1", commaVersion);
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(fileName, allLines);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the CruiseControl.Net standpoint everything looks fine. The CCNetLabel property should have the correct value. You could print it out with the [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yy0yx8d.aspx) task just to be sure.

I don't have any experience with C++ projects, but if you're not using Visual Studio 2010, [MSBuild is only delegating the build to VCBuild](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/efd7e001-57e2-478d-9621-1785d5fa10a9/) which could be the reason why the version you pass in is not being used (the same should happen if you manually call MSBuild with e.g. /p:version=1.2.3.4).

You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249221/vcbuild-task-in-msbuild-change-outputpath). Maybe you could solve your problem as well by overriding the vsprops file.